# React - Material UI - TextField controlled input with custom input component with custom props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, imaskjs

How can I pass custom props to the inputComponent?

For example, I have a MuiTextField component:

```
const CustomerSocialMask = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement, CustomProps>(
  function CustomerSocialMask(props, ref: any) {
    // deploy test
    const { onChange, ...other } = props;
    return (
      <IMaskInput
        {...other}
        mask="000.000.000-00"
        definitions={{
          '#': /[1-9]/,
        }}
        inputRef={ref}
        onAccept={(value: any) =>
          onChange({ target: { name: props.name, value } })
        }
        overwrite={false}
      />
    );
  },
);

<MuiTextField
  sx={{
    '& input[type=number]': {
      MozAppearance: 'textfield',
    },
    '& input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button': {
      WebkitAppearance: 'none',
      margin: 0,
    },
    '& input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
      WebkitAppearance: 'none',
      margin: 0,
    },
  }}
  variant="standard"
  multiline={data.fieldType === FieldType.LONG_TEXT}
  placeholder={data.settings.placeholder}
  fullWidth
  type={inputType}
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: prefix && (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Typography color="text.primary">{prefix}</Typography>
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
    endAdornment: suffix && (
      <InputAdornment position="start">
        <Typography color="text.primary">{suffix}</Typography>
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
    inputComponent: CustomerSocialMask,
  }}
  name={name}
  onChange={
    (data.settings as ShortTextSettings).valueType ===
      ValueType.CURRENCY || path === PersonalDetail.PHONE
      ? onChange
      : handleChange
  }
  onBlur={handleBlurWithFix}
  value={valueAdjusted}
  error={!!error}
  helperText={error}
/>
```

When I try to pass custom props to the inputComponent like:

```
inputComponent: <CustomerSocialMask customProp={something}/>,
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `inputComponent` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(Input2)`, expected a single ReactElement type.
```

So I must only provide refs to the inputComponent, but I can't pass external data / props to the forwardRef component. I want to use a customProp *inside* the CustomerSocialMask component por example. How would I do that? Couldn't find anything on the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/).

Comment: Is this not what the `inputProps` attribute is for (the lower case 'i' attribute not the upper case `InputProps`)? You are replacing the default input component and the component is passed all MUI calculated props + all user defined props from `inputProps`.

Comment: Turns out you were right, if I pass some arbitrary prop to lowercase inputProps I can access it inside the inputComponent in uppercase InputProps. Thank you very much sir! That wasn't obvious at all.

Comment: @JacobSmit you can post it as an answer to get the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Material UI `TextField` provides a few 'Props' style attributes to apply configuration to the child components that are combined to make the input.

Two of note are:

- `InputProps`: This provides properties to the Material UI component that is selected based on the `variant` property i.e. `OutlinedInput`, `FilledInput`, etc.
- `inputProps`: This provides properties to the underlying input which is being used, by default this is an `input`.

When using `InputProps.inputComponent` the underlying input is replaced with the provided component, this allows you to use `inputProps` to pass extra properties to configure the custom input.

Example:

```
<TextField
    InputProps={{
        inputComponent: CustomerSocialMask,
    }}
    inputProps={{
        customProp: something
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be very close to what you are doing, you just need to pass a function to inputComponent.

```
inputComponent: (props) => <CustomerSocialMask {...props} myCustomPropName={doSomething} />
```

Comment: This gives me `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'inputComponent' supplied to 'ForwardRef(InputBase2)'. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead?`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Hello MUITextfield inputProps attribute can accept only the types with a normal input tag can accept (varies depending on the type), however you can use the MUI `Input` component to pass with custom component to use, and there the inputProps is available so you can pass the props of your custom field.

I created a quick draft in this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-using-a-custom-component-with-input-compnent-zysvji?file=/src/App.tsx

I hope this helps.
E